# Wrong figure caption and number, attempt to implement APA 7 style

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, cleveref, apa7

I'm trying to adjust the figure formatting style to the APA 7 style. So far I'm doing well, but now I got an issue. When cross-referencing a figure in the text, it appears as "Figure 1a" instead of as "Figure 1". See below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%   APA 7 FIGURES
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareCaptionFormat{apa7figure}
{%
    \textbf{#1#2}\textit{\small #3}
}
\captionsetup{format=apa7figure, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
In order to undertand these concepts, please refer to \Cref{fig:objetocuadruple}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\caption[]{}
\subcaption[]{\textit{The quadruple object according to Graham Harman}}
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images/objeto-cuadruple-001.jpg}
\rule{\linewidth}{10em}
\end{center}
\footnotesize
\emph{Note:} Adapted from the \textit{Objetc-Oriented Ontology} witten by Harman on 2018.
\label{fig:objetocuadruple}
\end{figure}
```

Hope you can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I updated this answer to incorporate some information provided by the OP via the comments.)

Let's look at the following code block:

```
\begin{figure}[hp]
\caption[]{}
\subcaption[]{\textit{The quadruple object according to Graham Harman}}
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images/objeto-cuadruple-001.jpg}
\rule{\linewidth}{10em}
\end{center}
\footnotesize
\emph{Note:} Adapted from the \textit{Objetc-Oriented Ontology} witten by Harman in 2018.
\label{fig:objetocuadruple}
\end{figure}
```

The incorrect cross-reference to the figure -- "1a" instead of just "1" -- is caused by the needless (and inappropriate) use of `\subcaption`. I believe that what you really want is

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, textfont={it,small}, labelsep=newline,
              justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
```

in the preamble, followed by

```
\caption{The quadruple object according to Graham Harman}
```

inside the `figure` environment.

---

Remark: If the formatting of captions inside `table` environments should not be the same as that for `figure` environments, just (a) change

```
\captionsetup{...}
```

to

```
\captionsetup[figure]{...}
```

and (b) provide an appropriately designed

```
\captionsetup[table]{...}
```

instruction as well.

---

Here's a full MWE (minimum working example) and an associated screen shot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, textfont={it,small}, labelsep=newline,
              justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
              
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

In order to undertand these concepts, please refer to \cref{fig:objetocuadruple}.
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{The quadruple object according to Graham Harman}
\label{fig:objetocuadruple}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images/objeto-cuadruple-001}
\flushleft
\footnotesize
\emph{Note:} Adapted from \textit{Object-Oriented Ontology} (Harman, 2018).
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico thanks, but I'm 100% sure that's what I want. I need to follow APA 7 rules, where Figure # goes first without any other text attached. Next goes the figure title in italics. Then you place the figure and, if necessary, add notes at the end. So, I had to rely on that solution to comply with the APA 7 rules. More info here: https://normas-apa.org/wp-content/uploads/normas-apa-ejemplo-figura.png

Comment: @killthepixelnow -- It is most certainly the `\subcaption` expression that's causing the numbering problem. Why are you  using `\subcaption`? Is it the fact that you need a line break between "Figure 1" and the actual caption text? If so, the `caption` package affords a much better method to achieve this formatting goal. Please advise.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'm using \subcaption because that's the only way I found to separate Figure 1 from the caption itself. That means I need "Figure 1" to stand alone without any other text to the right (e.g. Figure 1: this is the caption). In APA 7 the figure title goes below "Figure 1." Any idea how to solve or fix that?

Comment: @killthepixelnow - Please see my revised answer. It does away with the subcaption stuff entirely, while being way more detailed in terms of `\captionsetup`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, it's a cleaner solution and now I don't have more problems regarding the numbering.